# If $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ are equidistributed, is $\{a_n\}\cup\{b_n\}$ equidistributed?

Tags: equidistribution

If $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ are equidistributed, is $\{a_n\}\cup\{b_n\}$ equidistributed ?

Comment: What do you mean with union of two sequences?

Comment: it's easy to prove that $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3,\dots$ is equidistributed.

Comment: @mathworker21 thank u ! I think I've got one !